# Unable to Cast COM Object of type

Tags: powershell, scripting

**Language:** Powershell

**Usage:** Login into Website

**Code:** *(NOTE: Actual values for lines 1., 2., and 4. have not been provided)*

```
$username = "User"
$password = "Password" 
$ie = new-object -com "InternetExplorer.Application"
$ie.navigate("URL")
$ie.visible =$true
$doc = $ie.document

$doc.getElementByID("username").value=$username
$doc.getElementByID("password").value=$password
$link = @($doc.getElementsByTagName('A')) | where-object {$_.innerText -eq 'Log In'}
$link.click
```

**Lines 1 thru 6 work perfectly and launch the default browser to the Login Page of the specified URL.**

**Lines 7 thru 9 produce the following errors:**

**Line 7:**

```
Exception calling "getElementById" with "1" argument(s): "Unable to cast 

COM object of type 'mshtml.HTMLDocumentClass' to interface type 

'mshtml.DispHTMLDocument'. This operation failed because the 

 QueryInterface call on the COM component for the interface with IID 

'{3050F55F-98B5-11CF-BB82-00AA00BDCE0B}' failed due to the following 

error: No such interface supported (Exception from HRESULT:

0x80004002 (E_NOINTERFACE))."

At line:1 char:20
+ $doc.getElementByID <<<< ("username").value=$username
+ CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodInvocationException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : DotNetMethodException
```

**Line 8:**

```
Exception calling "getElementById" with "1" argument(s): "Unable to cast 

COM object of type 'mshtml.HTMLDocumentClass' to interface type 

'mshtml.DispHTMLDocument'. This operation failed because the   

QueryInterface call on the COM component for the interface with IID 

'{3050F55F-98B5-11CF-BB82-00AA00BDCE0B}' failed due to the following 

error: The RPC server is unavailable. (Exception from HRESULT: 

0x800706BA)."

At line:1 char:20
+ $doc.getElementByID <<<< ("password")
+ CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodInvocationException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : DotNetMethodException
```

**Line 9:**

```
Exception calling "getElementsByTagName" with "1" argument(s): "Unable to 

cast COM object of type 'mshtml.HTMLDocumentClass' to interface type 

'mshtml.DispHTMLDocument'. This operation failed because the 

QueryInterface call on the COM component for the interface with IID 

'{3050F55F-98B5-11CF-BB82-00AA00BDCE0B}' failed due to the following 

error: The object invoked has disconnected from its clients. (Exception 

from HRESULT: 0x80010108 (RPC_E_DISCONNECTED))."

At line:1 char:36

+ $link = @($doc.getElementsByTagName <<<< ('A')) | where-object   
{$_.innerText -eq 'Log In'}

+ CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodInvocationException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : DotNetMethodException
```

I am not sure what this error is telling me and need some suggestions from some Powershell Gurus out there. I could not find anything in the stack that has this issue covered based on the use of Powershell.
Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 1):

What happens if you put sleep before looking into the document?

```
do { Sleep 1 } while( $ie.Busy -or $ie.ReadyState -ne 4 )
```

like this

```
$ie.visible =$true
do{Sleep 1} while( $ie.Busy -or $ie.ReadyState -ne 4 )
$doc = $ie.document
```